# some advice on how to write a window.resize function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to write a function that resizes the css widths of some elements when the browser window is resized, right now I dont seem to be getting things right and would love it if someone could help me out on where Im going wrong, my code so far is:

```
function windowResize() {
            $('#content').css('width', $windowWidth);
            $('#div.mySection').css('width', $windowWidth);
            $('#div.mySection .story').css('width', $windowWidth);
        }

$(document).ready(function() {

            var $windowWidth = $(window).width();               

            $(window).resize(function() {
                windowResize();
            });

        });
```

Im not sure if I have placed everything in its correct place, if someone could advise me on how I can make this code much better it would be great.

Thanks
Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to recalculate `window`'s new dimensions inside of the function you're running when the window resizes; otherwise, you will wind up with the same width being repeated forever. (Incidentally, your `$windowWidth` variable is outside of the scope of your `windowResize` function, which is why it is not being used now.)

```
function windowResize() {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width(); 
        $('#content').css('width', windowWidth);
        $('#div.mySection').css('width', windowWidth);
        $('#div.mySection .story').css('width', windowWidth);
    }

$(document).ready(function() {

        var $windowWidth = $(window).width();               

        $(window).resize(function() {
            windowResize();
        });

    });
```

By convention, variables storing jQuery objects are prefixed with `$`, so I removed that from `windowWidth`, which is a plain old Number.

Now, here's the caveat for your code: `resize` fires continuously in certain browsers, which means you are going to be running your handler continuously, too, which could be a very bad thing. Give [Ben Alman's throttle/debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) a try; it will limit the number of times your handler is called, "debouncing" or "throttling" execution to once for a given interval. That way, you'll achieve your effect without spamming resizes to your DOM elements (which can be painful and is a good way of locking a UI).

Comment: thanks @ajm how would I include this throttle or debounce in the code i currently have?

Comment: You'd download the plugin from Ben Alman's site, include it like any other jQuery plugin, and then bind it to `window.resize` like so: `$(window).resize($.throttle(100, windowResize))`. You can adjust that 100 ms value to whatever you like. `$.debouce` is called the same way, but works a little differently. Check the docs to see which works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

You're caching `$windowWidth` once so it will always be the same value.  Move `var $windowWidth = $(window).width();` inside the beginning of the `windowResize` function and your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

i would try it like this:

```
window.onresize = function(){
  var width = $(window).width();
  $('#content').css('width', width);
  $('#div.mySection').css('width', width);
  $('#div.mySection .story').css('width', width);
}
```

no need to wrap this into a domready-function or use jquery to attach the event (but doing so shouldn't be a problem).

you havn't stated what exactly is the problem (doesn't the event get fired? are you getting wrong results?), but the main thing to change is doing the width-calculation inside of the resize-function (otherwise wou'll only calculate that once and resue the variable, wich wouldn't have any effect).

Comment: Is the double semi-colon (`;;`) deliberate?